# How to remove empty th and td from thead and tbody from the HTML table which has no id, jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do we remove `th` from `thead` and `td` from `tbody` from the `table` which has no id element attached to it?

Please find the image for more reference.

[image]

I could not reuse any of the Javascript/jQuery functions available to remove empty `td` or `th`, since the table element has no id attached to it.

I won't be able to add any id for the table since it is *generated by JSF*, also only one HTML table is available in the page I am trying to delete the empty `th` and `td`.

Comment: Can you replace your image with actual code in the question, please?

Comment: you could query the table/html via the css classes?

Comment: @CodeF0x Thanks for the reply, this html code is generated by JSF as i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Please put the table as html in  your question (using browser developer tool you can copy the outerHtml of the table (Elements, right click table, copy outerHtml))

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily remove table cells without breaking the table.  Please post actual markup (not an image) and clarify the criteria for identifying what you want to remove.

Comment: _“also only one HTML table is available in the page”_ - well then the tag name alone would be enough to select it and nothing else already …?

Comment: To All the down voters ! see this question has a accepted answer. thank you very much for all your down votes. not sure if the down vote make sense for this question but still thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: you can use parent div selector to find the table and then its header and td elements to check if these elements are empty and delete it

```
$(function(){
  $("div.ui-datatable-tablewrapper table[role=grid] thead tr th").each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
      if(!text && !$(this).find('input').length)
     { 
       $(this).remove();
     }
  });

$("div.ui-datatable-tablewrapper table[role=grid] tbody tr td").each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text();
      if(!text && !$(this).find('input').length)
     { 
       $(this).remove();
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you!, this is really helpful and it does the job perfectly but It removes the td which has some input element, could you please help me understand to correct it, could you correct your code so that it removes only the empty th and td but not the th or td which has input element

Comment: happy to help you :)